# Android / HTTP GET not reading REST API properly

Tags: android, rest, authentication, android-asynctask, get

The content that is present in the URL

> http://sspapi-dev.samsungrs.com/health

is

```
[{"dspName":"openrtb","status":[{"type":"BIDREQ","state":"UP","avgTime":37},{"type":"VIEWTRACK","state":"UP","avgTime":10}]}]
```

but when I am reading the URL from my Android application, the output is

```
<html><head>    <title>MSG: Please wait while you are redirected</title>    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES"CONTENT="0">  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">       function onLoad()   {           window.location="http://182.16.0.1/userportal/?callerIP=182.16.11.24&requestURL=http%3A%2F%2Fsspapi-dev.samsungrs.com%2Fhealth";        }        </script></head><body onLoad="setTimeout('onLoad()', 1000);"><br><center>Please wait while you are redirected to the login page<br></center></body></html>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

    TextView t1;
    final String website = "http://sspapi-dev.samsungrs.com/health";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        Viewdata v1 = new Viewdata();
        v1.delegate = this;
        v1.execute(website);
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        t1.setText(output);
    }
}

class Viewdata extends Urltask{
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataModels) {
        super.onPostExecute(dataModels);

        delegate.processFinish(dataModels);
    }
}
```

JSONhelper.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JSONhelper{

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    String data;

    public String getdatafromurl(String url){
        String result = new String();
        try{
            URL url1 = new URL(url);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            result = buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

AsyncResponse.java

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Urltask.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

abstract class Urltask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        JSONhelper jsonhelper = new JSONhelper();
        String data = jsonhelper.getdatafromurl(params[0]);

        return data;
    }
}
```

By the way, it seems that the DefaultHttpClient package and its corresponding functions have been deprecated in API 22 (Android Lollipop) and removed from API 23 (Android Marshmallow). Making use of AsyncTask seems to be one of the alternative methods to it. But are there any other alternative methods that are available to it, that are closely related to the way of old DefaultHttpClient package and its corresponding functions themselves?

Comment: You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for data fetching. It is one of best libraries used for data fetching.

Comment: It was required to log in to Corporate Wi-Fi or some other mobile network before any data can be fetched from the Internet on a mobile device. Logging in to Corporate Wi-Fi by using official Windows 10 user name and password seemed to resolve this issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadContent();
    }

    public static String GET(OkHttpClient client, String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private void loadContent() {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                String response = "";
                try {
                    response = GET(client, "http://sspapi-dev.samsungrs.com/health");
                    //Parse the response string here

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return response;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Log.e("Response", s);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

> E/Response:
>   [{"dspName":"openrtb","status":[{"type":"BIDREQ","state":"UP","avgTime":37},{"type":"VIEWTRACK","state":"UP","avgTime":10}]}]

add this depandancies in gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort that you have put with my question, so I have upvoted for it. But your code does not resolve my issue, so that I cannot be able to accept your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Ironically, your code works out properly at my home, but not at my office where it is critical for it to work out properly to be able to show demo. Maybe that some other reason might be the cause for this problem, which I cannot be able to figure it out quite easily enough at all.

Comment: what issue is coming

Comment: When I read the URL from my workplace, the response still comes as: `<html><head>    <title>MSG: Please wait while you are redirected</title>    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES"CONTENT="0">  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">       ` ...

Comment: ... `function onLoad()   {           window.location="http://182.16.0.1/userportal/?callerIP=182.16.11.24&requestURL=http%3A%2F%2Fsspapi-dev.samsungrs.com%2Fhealth";        }        </script></head><body onLoad="setTimeout('onLoad()', 1000);"><br><center>Please wait while you are redirected to the login page<br></center></body></html>`. Your code works properly for me from my home, but not from my workplace. This means that some other intermediate layer is causing problems at my workplace. It may be independent of any piece of code written to fetch data from URL.